# Hard coded value variables in config/text file in python scripts

Tags: python-3.x, variables, configuration, pandas-groupby

I am using same variable names in multiple python scripts and want to avoid hard coding values for future changes. How do I keep all variables in one file like 'config' and use them in my python script?
Please help me.
I googled it too, but of no help.

Varibales:

```
todaysdate = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
folder_name = 'SourceFiles'
file_type = '.csv'
file_titles = ['Column1']
df['ID'] = df['Col1'].str[1:6]
df['EmpName'] = df['Col1'].str[7:37]
df['Salary'] = df['Col1'].str[38:58]
```

Comment: Any answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me try to help.

**Config.json File**

```
{
   "params": {
        "time": time.strftime("%Y%m%d"),
        "folder_name": 'SourceFiles',
        "file_type": '.csv',
  }
}
```

**Your Python file**

```
import json

with open('config.json', 'r') as c:
   params = json.load(c)["params"]     //params is variable from json file

todaysdate = params['time']
folder_name = params['folder_name']
file_type = params['file_type']
file_titles = ['Column1']
df['ID'] = df['Col1'].str[1:6]
df['EmpName'] = df['Col1'].str[7:37]
df['Salary'] = df['Col1'].str[38:58]
```

Any variable which you want to enter in config file just add it like i did and then call that variable as i did. If you change variable value in config file it automatically change every where.

Comment: Hello Adam, Thanks for the idea. Please let me know how the config file with my variables? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell me which variables you want to move in config file?

Comment: todaysdate = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
folder_name = 'SourceFiles'
file_type = '.csv'
file_titles = ['Column1']
df['ID'] = df['Col1'].str[1:6]
df['EmpName'] = df['Col1'].str[7:37]
df['Salary'] = df['Col1'].str[38:58]